# Reactive form angular 10 is not submitting when I hide an input based on condition

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form contains few textbox and radio box for show/hide text box. My requirement is when I submit the form either first name or last name should be submitted based on radio box selection. But when I hide either of field form is not submitting. Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div class="card m-3">
    <h5 class="card-header">Angular 10 Reactive Form Validation</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <select formControlName="title" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ><input (click)="firstName()" name="fname" type="radio"> show first name</div>
                <div ><input (click)="secondName()" name="fname" type="radio"> show first name</div>
               
                <div class="form-group col-5" *ngIf="firstNames">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-5" *ngIf="!firstNames">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
  </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReCaptchaV3Service } from 'ngx-captcha';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testproject';
  registerForm: any;
  siteKey: any;
  submitted = false;
  firstNames = true;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private reCaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    });

  }
  firstName(){
  this.firstNames = true;
  }
  secondName(){
    this.firstNames = false;
  }
  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    // display form values on success
    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value, null, 4));
  }

  onReset() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.registerForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, when you click register nothing happens right?

Comment: Hiding a form input does not make its corresponding item in the form not required anymore. You might want to use custom validation and/or get rid of the required validators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular form is always returning invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706113/angular-form-is-always-returning-invalid)

Comment: Yes Nothing happens

Comment: You should have an error in another place. The only way that this.registerForm.value "exclude" a control is that this FormControl was disabled -in this case you need use this.registerFrom.getRawValue(), see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue). You can check in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbaz5w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with your code. You problem is that if you don't fill both (firstName and lastName) the form is invalid

Comment: NOTE: you can see this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501076/dynamic-validation-based-on-conditions/60502565#60502565 if you want not check the erros if is "invisible" (the trick is also disabled the FormControl)